# how to handle multiple values through 'useState' hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, input, state

Here I've used `useState` hook in **React** to handle change in input field of form, but
I've repeated same code multiple times and I want to shorten it. Is there any possible way to handle multiple changes through single state and give output in object?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    
    const [enteredTitle, setEnteredTitle] = useState("");
    const [enteredPrice, setEnteredPrice] = useState("");
    const [enteredDate, setEnteredDate] = useState("");
    
    const titleChangeHandler = (e) => {
      setEnteredTitle(e.target.value);
    };
    const priceChangeHandler = (e) => {
      setEnteredPrice(e.target.value);enter code here
    };
    const DateChangeHandler = (e) => {
      setEnteredDate(e.target.value);
    };
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    
      const expenseData = {
        title: enteredTitle,
        price: enteredPrice,
        date: new Date(enteredDate),
      };
      props.newExpense(expenseData);
    
      setEnteredTitle("");
      setEnteredPrice("");
      setEnteredDate("");
    };
    
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="new-expense__controls">
          <div className="new-expense__control">
            <label htmlFor="">Title</label>
            <input
              onChange={titleChangeHandler}
              type="text"
              name="title"
              value={enteredTitle}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="new-expense__control">
            <label htmlFor="">Amount</label>
            <input
              onChange={priceChangeHandler}
              type="number"
              name="price"
              value={enteredPrice}
              min="0.01"
              step="0.01"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="new-expense__control">
            <label htmlFor="">Date</label>
            <input
              onChange={DateChangeHandler}
              type="date"
              name="date"
              value={enteredDate}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="new-expense__actions">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
    };
    export default ExpenseForm;
```

Comment: `useState({ title: "", price: "", date: "" })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each individual state value doesn't *have to be* a single value, it can be an object:

```
const [enteredData, setEnteredData] = useState({
  title: '',
  price: '',
  date: ''
});
```

And you can use a single change handler as long as your `<input>` elements have correct `name` attributes, since the `e.target` object also has that `name`.  For example:

```
const changeHandler = (e) => {
  setEnteredData({
    ...enteredData,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
};
```

This would update the state object to include all the properties of the current state object, but specify one property (from the given `name`) to have the new given `value`.

Then your `<input>` elements can just use that object and handler function:

```
<input
  onChange={changeHandler}
  type="text"
  name="title"
  value={enteredData.title}
/>
```